# expression "as an affirmation of its efficiency, we show that"

Tags: expressions

Is the expression "as an affirmation of its efficiency, we show that" correct and adequate for a scientific text? Or should it be "as a confirmation of its efficiency, we show that"?

Comment: That really all depends on whether your intentions are to `affirm` it or `confirm` it.  A dictionary should help resolve your dilemma.

Comment: Voting to close as general reference. Please look up the words in a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is valid grammatically, but it's a baroque way of conveying the meaning. Why use a verb that's been turned into a noun (*affirm* -> *affirmation*) when you can just use the verb, and make it easier to understand?

> To affirm its efficiency, we show that...

... and there are more conventional verbs you could use.

> To demonstrate its efficiency, we show that...
>
> To confirm its efficiency, we show that...

In a scientific paper, you should use the most straightforward language possible.